# Granting User Permissions to IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to give a coworker rights to IIS on a server, because currently he can't see the server in IIS manager.  What rights do I need to grant him?  I tried adding him to the IIS_USRS, but he still can't see the server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would think at least in the "Users" group, however, will probably have to be an Admin to make many changes...Try right clicking on "Start Page" and then select "Connect to a Server..." and type localhost, click Next, then Finish, see if that connects to the local IIS install.

Answer (score 1):

Also be sure that the Web Management Service is started. As default, when this role feature is installed, its startup type will be *Manual*, set it to *Automatic* if you want to always be able to connect to your web server

Answer (score 0):

Is the coworker logging into the server to use IIS Manager or from their workstation? If the server is IIS 7.5, you need to add your coworker to the IIS Manager Permissions for the website you want them to manage. The Management Service role must be installed and set to Windows credentials unless you want to manage IIS credentials. Doing that will let them remotely connect from their IIS Manager tool (Win7) or the IIS7 Administration tool you can install in XP.